# Is a holder of a German unlimited residence permit allowed to work in the UK?

Tags: uk, work, permits

I am asking for a friend who is interested to take up employment for a company who requires her service for max 6 weeks in a year. She will remain in Germany most of the time.

So is it possible for her to work in the UK with the electronic (EU) unlimited residence permit?

Comment: There are three different kinds of German unlimited residence permits: a) Niederlassungserlaubnis b) Erlaubnis zum Daueraufenthalt-EU c) Blaue Karte EU. All three are now given in electronic form. The specific kind is mentioned on the front under "Art des Titels". Which does your friend have?